# Is it possible to sign NuGet package generated in ASP.NET vNext?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have a project (.kproj) that outputs a library. Is it possible to sign the .dlls inside of my .nupkg?  It seems to call klr.exe with my project folder and just output a NuGet package.

I looked through [Managing Assembly and Manifest Signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247066.aspx) but I can't find the Signing tab or anything related to it.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5.

Comment: I believe that signing DLLs inside an ASP.NET 5 project is not currently supported. Signing the package itself is something that's currently being worked on.

Comment: It seems that there will be no more strong naming for assemblies in Core CLR.

Comment: I know question is a bit old but things have changed is it comes to signing CoreCLR and CoreFX - all .NET Core assemblies are strong named. Check https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/oss-signing.md